# JMeter can not find method with BSF Sampler

Tags: javascript, exception, jmeter

I'm using `BSF Sampler` with this javascript:

```
var tokenPass = '1234';
var serialNo = '1234578740905549583';
var str = 'hello';
var hashedpassword = Packages.ml.bn.security.CUpload.signDocument(tokenPass, serialNo, str, false);
vars.put('HASHEDPASSWORD',hashedpassword);
```

I copy the jar file in lib folder of JMeter (the classpath). The jar file has a class named `CUpload.java` in `ml.bn.security` package. The class has a method named `signDocument` with this signature:

```
public SignInfo signDocument(String pin, String serialNumber, String document, boolean isCheked) throws Throwable {
...
}
```

When I run the Jmeter, I get error:

> Response code: 500
>
> Response message: org.apache.bsf.BSFException:
> JavaScript Error: Java class
> "ml.bn.security.CUpload" has no public instance
> field or method named "signDocument"

What's the problem it can not find the method in that class file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object has an instance method not static method so you are using it in a wrong way.

To use it you need to build the Object then call the method:

```
var signer = new ml.bn.security.CUpload();
var hashedpassword = signer.signDocument(tokenPass, serialNo, str, false);
vars.put('HASHEDPASSWORD',hashedpassword);
```

I would advise you also to use JSR223+Groovy instead of BSF.